# Repairing the headers of phylip bioinformatics files to accurately reflect the updated number of samples in the file(s)

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics, wc

I have a dataset that I am working with made up of phylip files that I have been editing. Phylip format is a bioinformatics format that contains as a header the number of samples and the sequence length, followed by each sample and its sequence. for example:

```
5 10
sample_1 gaatatccga
sample_2 gaatatccga
sample_3 gaatatcgca
sample_4 caatatccga
sample_5 gaataagcga
```

My issue is that in trimming these datasets, the sample number in the header no longer is accurate (e.g. in above example might say five, but I've since trimmed to have only three samples). What I need to do is to replace that sample count with the new, accurate sample count but I cannot figure out how to do so without losing the sequence length number (e.g. the 10).

I have 550 files so simply doing this by hand is not an option. I can for-loop the wc but again I need to retain that sequence length information and somehow combine it with a new, accurate wc.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post the actual text in a code block.

Comment: Also, it's unclear how the number should be changed. Always to 3?

Comment: ok thank you, will do in the future. Not always to three as the sample number is different across files but most of the files have been edited and so the new number of samples is often fewer than what is currently stated in the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -v samples="$(($(grep -c . input)-1))" 'NR == 1 { $1=samples }1' input
```

`samples` will be set to the number of lines in the `input` file minus one (since you aren't counting the header line).

`awk` will then change the first column of the first line to the new sample number and print everything.

---

```
$ cat input
5 10
sample_1 gaatatccga
sample_2 gaatatccga
sample_3 gaatatccga
$ awk -v samples="$(($(grep -c . input)-1))" 'NR == 1 { $1=samples }1' input
3 10
sample_1 gaatatccga
sample_2 gaatatccga
sample_3 gaatatccga
```

---

With GNU awk you can use the `-i` flag to modify the files in place but I would prefer to make a second set of modified files to ensure the correct changes have been made.

Something like:

```
for file in *.phy; do
    awk -v samples="$(($(grep -c . "$file")-1))" 'NR == 1 { $1=samples }1' "$file" > "${file}.new"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use `ed` (of course!):

```
for f in input*
do 
  printf '1s/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*/%d\nw\nq' $(( $(wc -l < "$f") - 1 )) | ed -s "$f"
done
```

This loops over the files (named, for example `input`-something) and sends a simple ed-script to `ed`:

- on line `1`, search and replace (`s//`) one or more digits at the beginning of the line with another number -- that replacement number being the result of computing the line length of the input minus one
- after that, `w` write the file out and
- then `q` quit ed

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, run:

```
:execute '1s/^[0-9]\+/' . (line('$')-1) . '/'
```

(Thanks also to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19983/4676) for pointing me in the right direction.)

You can also do this in a loop, e.g. using `:bufdo` or just a shell `for` loop.